# What happend to the close votes on this question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

[Recommendations for Photo Editing/Organization Software?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20872/recommendations-for-photo-editing-organization-software)

This question had 4 close votes(as noted by me in the comments) on 03/07/12. Now it has none. Did a moderator close/unclose to clear the votes? Or how else can they be removed? Why was this done? I don't see any note from a moderator or others if this was an action taken by someone. Maybe after a certain time they get cancelled if the required 5 are not voted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close votes age away and expire as part of a regular process.  A close vote will expire after four days.

However, if the question has less than 100 views, the close votes will not age until it crosses that 100 views threshold.

For more details, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99345/140548).

You can only cast a single close vote and a single reopen vote per question.

Comment: That is good to know for this site. With the amount of users that are active in flagging to close, this probably comes up somewhat often here.

Comment: Interesting...learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "close" link, and if you were one of the voters-to-close, you'll be told you already voted. There's a bug here — not sure if it's just a display bug or a functional one. (I've actually been seeing this for a while... should have said something I guess....)

Comment: Yes, I have "already voted to close" although the question has zero votes shown right now. Bug.

Comment: FWIW same question shows same behavior for me.

Comment: Looking at Rebecca's answer, this doesn't seem to be a bug. You still have used your vote, even if it expired.

Comment: Yup, apparently so. Lesson learned: if I want something old closed, edit the post first so it gets bumped to the front page so other people might also see it and vote. :)